# How to validate a float number on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this function with a regular expression for validating integer values with no leading zeros when typing in an input :

```
$('input.input-number').keyup(function(e) {
    var regexp = (/[^0-9]|^0+(?!$)/g);

    if (regexp.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(regexp, '');
    }
});
```

How to adapt it to take into account a float number.
The function should :

- do not allow multiple '.' sign : 123.342.08 = not valid / 123.34208 = valid
- do not allow '.' sign at the begining of the string : .012 = not valid / 0.012 = valid
- do not allow leading zeros in the integer part : 00.012 = not valid / 0.012 = valid
- do not allow trailing zeros in thr decimal part : 10.012000 = not valid / 10.012 = valid

Comment: @guest271314 They're requiring one and only 1 zero can prepend the decimal point

Comment: Why? Just let the JavaScript engine parse a valid number into a float representation and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!` operator, `RegExp` `/[^\d.]+|^(0{2}|\.)|(0$)|\.(?=\.|.+\.)/` where `false` is returned if string does not contain only digits and `"."` character, begins with two or more `"0"` characters or `"."` character, or end of string is `"0"`, or string contains `"."` character followed by `"."` or one or more digits followed by `"."`, else return `true` with `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```js
const re = /[^\d.]+|^(0{2}|\.)|(0$)|\.(?=\.|.+\.)/;

console.log(
  !re.test("123.342.08") // false
, !re.test(".012") // false
, !re.test("00.012") // false
, !re.test("10.012000") // false
, !re.test("0.012") // true
, !re.test("10.012") // true
, !re.test("123.34208") // true
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, I've edited my initial post because multiple '.' are of course not allowed in a float number.

Comment: @Ouatataz Are you sure those are all the conditions?

Comment: Yes I am, these are the only conditions I need here.

Comment: Thank you ! your regex works like a charm statically. My only problem is that when binding it to the keyup event (like in the function of my initial post), it does not work very well with leading zeros (ie if I want to type a number starting with 0.) nor with trailing zeros (if I want to type a number like 123.1201).

Comment: Not sure how that issue is related to original Question? 
 What is expected result? Why do you not use a `<button>` or other element for user to click when they intend to submit the value?

Comment: I could use a button, but in this specific case, I need live validation

Comment: What is expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @guest271314, I finally upgraded the initial function that can now handle integer or float input validation (but, without taking care of trailing zeros in the decimal part).

This is what I use to validate number inputs for integer or float values (unobtrusive style with jQuery):

```js
$('input[name="number"]').keyup(function(e) {
    var float = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-float'));

    /* 2 regexp for validating integer and float inputs *****
        > integer_regexp : allow numbers, but do not allow leading zeros
        > float_regexp : allow numbers + only one dot sign (and only in the middle of the string), but do not allow leading zeros in the integer part
    *************************************************************************/
    var integer_regexp = (/[^0-9]|^0+(?!$)/g);
    var float_regexp = (/[^0-9\.]|^\.+(?!$)|^0+(?=[0-9]+)|\.(?=\.|.+\.)/g);

    var regexp = (float % 1 === 0) ? integer_regexp : float_regexp;
    if (regexp.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(regexp, '');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-float="1" id="number" name="number" placeholder="integer">
<input type="text" data-float="0.1" id="number" name="number" placeholder="float">
```